# Customizing Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less, customization

So I am working on a site that uses bootstrap. I need to customize many of the default bootstrap look and feel - Mainly the color scheme and rounded boxes. I know `Less` is used for entering default values in variables and recompiling it. I do not know `Less` but I do not think it will be very hard to learn.

But for the ease of testing various color schemes what I am doing is adding a custom class to every element I want to test. For e.g. I want to change the look and feel of the `jumbotron`. I am doing

```
<div class = "jumbotron test-jumbotron">
Content here..
</div>
```

`test-jumbotron` is my test class. Then in my CSS I do:

```
.test-jumbotron
{
  border: "<my-test-border-style>" !important;
  background: "<my-test-background-style>" !important;
}
```

My idea is that once I have nailed all the styles and effects I need, I can use `Less` (still don't know how, but that is a question for another day) to integrate my `test-*` styles into `Bootstrap` and then delete all the `test-*` styles from my files.

I think this might come across as an opinionated question - but will this approach work? I do not want the best optimal world-class solution, just want to know if this can work, or is there a chance I will hit a road-block later down the path and have to retrace all my way back?

Comment: This looks a bit tedious (if we're talking about "colour scheme and rounded boxes"). Bootstrap colours and border radii are controlled with just about (or even less than) 20 variables you can modify in a few minutes. I'd suggest you to learn just a bit more about typical Bootstrap customization workflows *before* you start to invent your own (for instance look at something like http://bootswatch.com and see how they do their customization). And never miss http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thank you for your feedback and the links. Actually my changes are more than just the color schemes and boxes, but I hear what you said.

Comment: Yep. Eiether way, let's take the jambotron as an example. Take a look at the [`jumbotron.less` source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/less/jumbotron.less). You can see it's just 40 lines long and since Less is not *that* different from CSS I guess you'll quickly understand what is what there and what exactly you need to modify to change its styles (and what properties you need to set/override if something is not covered by Bootstrap itself). That way you'll advance much faster than almost blindly overriding `.jumbotron` class properties and then... what?

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2014/6/blog_template_using_bootstrap3_part2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not customized the bootstrap before downloading.. their website offers the capability..

[customized bt3](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

then just write some tweaks to improve and change what do you need.. in css not less or sass example remove the default radius of navbar

```
.navbar { border-radius: 0 !important; }
```

but if you do want to learn all of this then your approach I think is the best way to know what is actually happening..

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are trying to do, but the fact that you are rewriting all of the css that you want to change and giving it another selector name defeats the purpose of LESS.

**Extremely Simplified Description of LESS -**

With LESS, think of it as a variable replacement. At the top of the css page (.less) you would create a bunch of variables (let's say for colors) and then in the body of your css file (.less) you would reference those variables.

If you ever want to change the color scheme of your site, you would just change the variable colors at the top of the page (.less).

**Simple Solution**

> For your testing purposes I would make a duplicate copy of the bootstrap.css file and reference that in your page (something like BootstrapTest.css) instead of the official bootstrap.css file. No need to add any of your new class names to the tags or in the page. Just edit the BootstrapTest.css.

Comment: The reason for not using another version of bootstrap is because for e.g. I might not need jumbotron class changed everywhere. Some classes might, some might not. I am using prefixes to mark which bootstrap classes can be overwritten and which shouldn't be.

Comment: Ah, I see. If that is the case then I would continue on your path, keeping the new styles inside of a new file. I would name the selectors with a legitimate name since they are in a separate file. Then, I believe that you would have to work your styles back into a LESS bootstrap file by hand.